# iphone- is it true that an app with push notification service needs to be on the app store?

Tags: iphone

If i wanted to test an app with push notification service, does it have to be approved in the app store?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. You can use push notifications without ever submitting to the App Store via development or "Ad-Hoc" builds. You will however need a signed certificate from Apple, as push messages are routed through their network. Certs can be acquired with a paid Apple developer account.